# What are the differences between "I fell off / out / down / over / in"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

What are the differences between "**I fell off / out / down / over**"?

What I understand is that:

- "**off**" is opposite of "**on**". So if you are "**on something**" and "**you fell off**", then you are not on it.
- "**out**" is opposite of "**in**". So if you are "**in something**" and "**you fell out**", then you are not in it.
- "**out**" is opposite of "**in**". So if you are "**in something**" and "**you fell out**", then you are not in it. And if you are "**outside something**" and "**you fell in**", then you are in it.
- "**down**" is opposite of "**up**". So if you are "**up there**" and "**you fell down**", then you are on a lower position.
- "**over**" is from one side to another side. So if you are "**one one side**" and "**you fell over**", then you are on the other side it.

But **I may be wrong.**

Comment: _Fall down_ can _also_ mean 'fall to the ground from an upright position'. _Fall over_ can mean the same thing, but if you _fall over something_, that thing causes you to trip

Comment: You can also search sources for a phrase like "fall off", "fall over", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your definitions are mostly correct but there is more to say.

As you state fall off implies you were on something and then you fell so that you were no longer on it. You fall off a ladder for instance.

Fall out implies being in something and then falling so you were no longer inside. So you might fall out of the door. Note that it also has figurative uses, if you fall out with someone then it means you are now no longer a friend with them. If a military detachment is instructed to fall out it means they can leave their formation and disperse.

@KateBunting has already explained in a comment that the usual use of fall down is when a part of your body above the knee inadvertently comes into contact with the ground or at least somewhere lower than it was. Fall over means the same as fall down but can also take a direct object telling us what exactly it  was that you tripped over and which made you fall.